# How to convert SQL to LINQ?

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, linq

Here is my IsValid user login code in MVC4 model.

I'm trying to have my SQL command convert to LINQ.

How can I convert it to LINQ way?

```
public bool IsValid(string _username, string _password)
{
    using (var cn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename" + 
        @"='C:\Tutorials\1 - Creating a custom user login form\Creating " + 
        @"a custom user login form\App_Data\Database1.mdf';Integrated Security=True")) 
    {
        string _sql = @"SELECT [Username] FROM [dbo].[System_Users] " + 
            @"WHERE [Username] = @u AND [Password] = @p";
        var cmd = new SqlCommand(_sql, cn);
        cmd.Parameters
            .Add(new SqlParameter("@u", SqlDbType.NVarChar))
            .Value = _username;
        cmd.Parameters
             .Add(new SqlParameter("@p", SqlDbType.NVarChar))
             .Value = Helpers.SHA1.Encode(_password);
        cn.Open();
        var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (reader.HasRows)
        {
            reader.Dispose();
            cmd.Dispose();
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            reader.Dispose();
            cmd.Dispose();
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: One does not simply convert SQL to LINQ.

Comment: Umm... it's not okay to check username and password like that. Where's your hash function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you've LINQ or any ORM setup for your application, it  can be converted to simple LINQ statement.

```
return _dbContext.Users.Any(c=>c.UserName == _username && c.Password == Helpers.SHA1.Encode(_password));
```

Answer (score 0):

I would first look at using an Entity Data Model like the ones in Entity Framework (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/ef.aspx) to model your database objects in C# and add one to your project.

Then I would create a Stored Procedure in your DB to handle the execution of the SQL statement, passing in the parameters you want to test against.

Then, I would import the stored procedure into the Data Model and run a LINQ query against it.

Something along the lines of:

```
var valid = (from users in context.CheckUserMembership(userName: userName, password: password)
select new User
{
   UserId = users.UserId,
   UserName = users.Username
}).Count() > 0;
```

Where context is a reference to the Data Context generated by the Entity Data Model wizard and CheckUserMembership is the imported stored procedure containing your SQL statement.